# Is it possible to modify the auto-install script for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express in the set up program for VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created a new setup program (THANKS! for MS bringing that back!) to install my application. I noticed that SQL Server 2008 R2 Express can be installed through the setup program as a prerequisite. It worked great on a standalone server but it's failing on install if the server is in a domain.

I ran the setup program manually and it's not auto-selecting the service for SQL Server Express which is why I think it's bombing. If I set that on the manual install, it runs.

Does anyone how I can modify the setup for the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express install when it's being installed through a visual studio 2013 setup program?  The command below was auto generated and I can't find any place to change it....  I believe it should be `/sqlsvcaccount="NT Authority\SYSTEM"` instead of `Network Service`. If I manually select `Network Service` in the setup program I get

> Network service or local service is not permitted for the SQL Server service on a domain controller

Or perhaps you may know a way around this?

the error I'm getting is this:

> Installing using command 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDD8FF.tmp\SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' and parameters '/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount="NT Authority\Network Service" /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'
>   **Process exited with code -2068578304**

Comment: You really should not install SQL Server on a domain controller, there are many stuble consaquences of turning a computer in to a domain controller, many which will have great impact if you install SQL server.

Comment: I understand that and in production installs this does not occur.  This is on my VMWare workstation being used to test the application.

Comment: I haven't played with installing SQL as a prerequisite, but I have done a lot of work with programmatically installing it unattended. You need to conditionally specify the service credentials depending one whether it is a DC or not. I would suggest packaging the SQL installer as a resource, extracting it at install time, then running it with the appropriate command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new package with SQL express and set up the variables I needed.  After I got it to work, I thought about it and it would have been possible to modify the original install.  However, it would not have been a good idea to do so because the "default" SQL package would have had my new defaults and subsequent setup programs would have those defaults.  It definitely was best to do a custom installer.